# Properly call anonymous method with async

Tags: .net, .net-core

I want to use the anonymous method in this code fragment:

```
Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i => async () =>
{
    await new System.Net.Http.HttpClient().GetAsync("www.somesite12345.com");
}));
```

But the "Select" has the "red wiggles" and the compiler errors out with:

> The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I know this can be re-coded with a call to a regular method inside the Lambda, but I was wondering if there a way to keep this as an anonymous method?

Thanks.

Comment: THe async and await cancel each other out - you can remove them, an optimization.

Comment: Post exact, compiling code. There is no WebClient in that namespace and it does not have a GetAsync().

Comment: You probably mean HttpClient and you are using it wrong (google that).

Comment: Yep, HttpClient, that was a "typo". My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `i => async () => {}` with `async i => {}`

But, if all you need inside this method is `GetAsync` then you could also just return task and await the `Task.WhenAll`:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(_ => client.GetAsync("http://www.somesite12345.com")));
}
```